# java.net.SocketTimeoutException in ImageLoader of LazyList in Android

Tags: android, lazylist

I am using `LazyList` for my Custom `ListView` which contains `ImageView` and `TextView`. It loaded hardly some images and after sometimes It gives me error.
**ImageLoader :**

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
}
```

**LogCat :**

```
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at com.mytestbuddy.teacher.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:72)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at com.mytestbuddy.teacher.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:55)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at com.mytestbuddy.teacher.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:147)
05-29 13:54:25.263: W/System.err(20615):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
05-29 13:54:25.273: W/System.err(20615):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-29 13:54:25.273: W/System.err(20615):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-29 13:54:25.273: W/System.err(20615):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-29 13:54:25.273: W/System.err(20615):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-29 13:54:25.273: W/System.err(20615):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your internet connection. This happens when your internet connection is slow.